# Fade In and Reflect CSS, Doesnt work

Tags: html, css, reflection

I am trying to do someting like this **http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/HoverEffects/Ex5.html**, where the reflection of the image shows under , however it doesnt work. I have done inspect element, and used their code accordingly, but it doesnt work on my site. When I do inspect element on my own computer in Chrome, that is when I see the reflection.   let me know if you need any clarification. here is my code that I have [http://jsfiddle.net/srvcm/1](http://jsfiddle.net/srvcm/)

```
.ex img {
    <!--margin: 25px;-->
    opacity: 0.9;
    border: 1px solid #eee;

    /*Transition*/
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;

    /*Reflection*/
    -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(.7, transparent), to(rgba(0,0,0,0.1)));


}


.ex img:hover {  
   opacity: 1;

   /*Reflection*/
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(.7, transparent), to(rgba(0,0,0,0.7)));

   /*Glow*/
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is working, actually. The `to` defined in the default state is too faint to really see. Also, the image itself is mostly dark on the bottom, so it isn't noticeable.

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/srvcm/1/

Comment: Oh wow your absolutely right, thanx man

Comment: Oh another question, this only works for Chrome, is there Fire Fox code format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code Works perfectly on its own